# How to disable sorting while dragging and sort only after drop using the vue.draggable library?

Tags: vue.js, sorting, vuejs2, drag-and-drop, sortablejs

The normal behavior of the Vue.Draggable is to sort/move the elements while they are being dragged.

I want to disable this and sort only once the element is dropped somewhere.

For a visual representation. Here is the current/normal behavior: [image: vue.draggable behavior]

And here is a gif of the expected behavior: [image: drag and drop expected behavior]

There is a plugin to change some of the functionality of the SortableJS library, its name is "Swap", it stops the elements movement while dragging, but once dropped, the elements get swapped, which is not what I want.

Any ideas?

I do not understand where these elements are stored. Basically, there is a data property, which is a list of the sortable elements. It is interesting that, while dragging, visually, the elements are rearranged, but regarding the data property, every element stays at its original index and nothing is changed.

Where is that change in the order happening?

Comment: After going through the issues in the SortableJS library to look for someone with my case, I came a cross a comment from a member of the library stating that [this movement can't be disabled](https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable/issues/1410#issuecomment-448801476).

This was after numerous attempts to remove this "sliding" effect.

The only "way" is to use the "swap" plugin, but it changes the behavior of sorting to swapping, which isn't something that I want also.